# Decimal not rounding properly

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding-error

I have a decimal called 'sum' and its value is `5824088.999120m`, but when I try to round it to 3 decimals I get `5824088.998m` instead of `5824088.999m`. It decrements instead of leaving `5824088.999m`.

Why is it? Here's my code:

```
List<decimal> quantityList = QuantityList();
List<decimal> priceList = PriceList();

decimal destination = 5824088.999M;
decimal sum = 0M;
bool lifesaver = false;

for (int x = 0; x < priceList.Count; x++)
{
    sum = 0M;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3500; i++)
    {
        priceList[x] += 0.001M;
        sum = 0M;
        for (int y = 0; y < priceList.Count; y++)
        {
            decimal multipleProduct = priceList[y] * quantityList[y];
            sum = sum + multipleProduct;
            Console.WriteLine(priceList[y] + " " + quantityList[y]);

            sum = Math.Round(sum, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        if (sum == destination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The new number is " + priceList[x] + " and it is the {0} element!", x);
            lifesaver = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (sum > destination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Limit exceeded!");
        }

        if (i == 3499)
        {
            priceList[x] -= 3.500M;
        }
        if (lifesaver == true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }//Second for loop

    if (lifesaver == true)
    {
        break;
    }
}//Main for loop
```

The lists are in another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have round up error *accumulation* and thus the total is wrong:

```
  for (int y = 0; y < priceList.Count; y++) {
    ...
    sum = Math.Round(sum, 3); // <- this accumulates round up errors
    ...
  }
```

imagine that the `priceList` contains

```
  priceList = new List<Decimal>() {
    1.0004M, 1.0004M, 1.0004M};
```

while `quantityList` are all 1's; the `sum` will be

```
1.000M, 2.000M, 3.000M
```

while the actual total is

```
Math.Round(1.0004M + 1.0004M + 1.0004M, 3)
```

**3.001M**. 
Possible remedy is not rounding up *prematurely*:

```
   for (int y = 0; y < priceList.Count; y++) {
      ...
      //DONE: comment out this: no premature rounding (within the loop)
      // sum = Math.Round(sum, 3);
      //DONE: but format out when printing out
      Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0:F3}", sum);
      ...
   } 

   // round up (if you want) after the loop
   sum = Math.Round(sum, 3);
```

Comment: @Reza Taibur: by *removing/commenting out* `sum = Math.Round(sum, 3);` - just do not round up *within the loop* (prematurely), add up values only and format them while printing out. If you want to round up, do it *after* the loop

Answer (score 0):

You should look into MidpointRounding (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx) and add this to your Math.Round function. Like this: `sum = Math.Round(sum, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven);`, the other option you have is `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`, which might be better for you.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that using AwayFromZero does round in a different way that ToEven. If you have tried it, why don't you tell us that you did, and what the results were. You can't just expect that we all know what you have tried and what you didn't. "Does not work I have already tried it.", is not really a decent response to an answer, I would argue.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `Math.Round` method.

Here is the MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.round(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This method is equivalent to calling the Round(Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding) method with a mode argument of MidpointRounding.ToEven.When d is exactly halfway between two rounded values, the result is the rounded value that has an even digit in the far right decimal position. For example, when rounded to two decimals, the value 2.345 becomes 2.34 and the value 2.355 becomes 2.36. This process is known as rounding toward even, or banker's rounding. It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently rounding a midpoint value in a single direction.

You should try the `Math.Round(decimal, int32, System.MidpointRounding)`, which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try calling it with the `MidPointRounding` enum `AwayFromZero` value.

Example:

```
decimal d = 5824088.999120M;
decimal rounded = Math.Round(d, 3, System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
Console.WriteLine(rounded.ToString());
```

Logs `5824088.999`

From remarks:

> The decimals parameter specifies the number of significant decimal places in the return value and ranges from 0 to 28. If decimals is zero, an integer is returned.
>
> In a midpoint value, the value after the least significant digit in the result is precisely half way between two numbers. For example, 3.47500 is a midpoint value if it is to be rounded two decimal places, and 7.500 is a midpoint value if it is to be rounded to an integer. In these cases, the nearest value can't be easily identified without a rounding convention, which is specified by the mode argument. The Round(Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding) method supports two rounding conventions for handling midpoint values.
>
> Rounding away from zero.
>   Midpoint values are rounded to the next number away from zero. For example, 3.75 rounds to 3.8, 3.85 rounds to 3.9, -3.75 rounds to -3.8, and -3.85 rounds to -3.9. This form of rounding is represented by the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero enumeration member.
>   Rounding away from zero is the most widely known form of rounding.
>
> Rounding to even, or banker's rounding
>   Midpoint values are rounded to the nearest even number. For example, both 3.75 and 3.85 round to 3.8, and both -3.75 and -3.85 round to -3.8. This form of rounding is represented by the MidpointRounding.ToEven enumeration member.
>   Rounding to nearest is the standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical operations. It conforms to IEEE Standard 754, section 4. When used in multiple rounding operations, it reduces the rounding error that is caused by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction. In some cases, this rounding error can be significant.

Check this [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ul4prp) also. If you run it, you will see precisely your expected value `5824088.999`

Comment: I need the exact value of sum not .000 at the end

Comment: @RezaTaibur I'm afraid I cannot understand what you need. Can you please clarify what exactly you need in your question so we can help you?

Comment: Thank you but I already got the answer(see Dmytri Bychenko's answer)